# Google Glass Camera: how to take a picture with glass activated from the phone

Tags: android, camera, google-glass

this is my first question on here so go easy on me.

I am trying to integrate use of Google Glass's camera into an Android app, and I am trying to figure out if there is a best way (or even any way) to do this.

I have an android app running on the phone/tablet and there is no way for me to get it running on the glass.  It is just too computationally expensive and uses external hardware not supported by the glass.  At some point in my app (on the phone) I call the camera API and take a picture with the phone/tablet camera.

I need a way to offload this picture taking to a paired glass.

I have thought of several approaches but here are the problems:

1 - use the mirror API, call mirror API from the phone, have it pass the command along to the glass then publish the picture to the web to be retrieved from the android phone - problem - looks like you can't call a camera function so this is a non-starter

2 - continuously programmatically stream pictures from glass to the phone using an app in GLASS that publishes to the phone as a server/client relationship.  This seems like it is too hack-ey if glass will even let me do this with sufficient frequency.

Is there any way to access the camera of a paired Glass via. bluetooth connection from an android phone app that I am not thinking of?  I have seen JoeGlass, which doesn't seem to get me there, and I have seen the MyGlass app (which also seems kinda useless for this purpose)

to add to this problem, I don't have the glass handy and will only have access to it for a couple of days and need to get some ideas down on "paper" first.

Comment: Is there any special reason you want to take a picture from your paired phone? You can take a picture from glass directly by implementing camera api (same as that of android) and take pictures using gestures as well as voice commands. I can provided you the code for doing that if you want.

Comment: no i've got the code for that and generally understand how it works.  The problem is that I have some power/processor hungry code working on a sensor array attached to the phone that needs to be able to see what you are looking at in near-real time (or at least within a few seconds).

I have the code on the phone set to take the picture when necessary.  I just need the picture to be whatever the person is LOOKING at, hence glass.  Yeah I know I could glue the tablet to someone's head but that's not the task I've been asked to do.

Comment: I researched from my end and it seems like the second option which is streaming the pictures from glass to the phone using an app in Glass that published to the phone as a client/server relationship looks better. The only thing is there are no existing api or protocol to do that for now, you have to build your own.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I found something on stack exchange explaining how to do that a few weeks ago.  But is a triggering event on the phone (to trigger the picture in glass) possible?  Or will i just need to constantly stream the pictures?

Comment: So after a long hunt, I got this reply from a Google Glass developer: "There are no optical zoom on Glass so the zoom that occurs is actually done using software: it is possible that those developers use a combination of both the Android zoom feature and custom zoom/interpolation algorithm."